# Java property values loaded in constructor are being reverted after the constructor?

Tags: java, oop

I'm noticing some strange behavior. I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class BaseFoo
{
   public BaseFoo(String key)
   {
       Data data = Something.load( key );
       load( data );
   }

   public abstract void load(Data data);
}


public class Foo extends BaseFoo
{
   @Expose public long id = 0;
   @Expose public String name =  "";
   //...

   public Foo(String key)
   {
      super(key);
   } 

   @Override
   public void load(Data data)
   {
     this.id = data.id;
     this.name = data.name;
     //snip setting misc other fields
   }
}
```

Now, if I do the following:

```
Foo f = new Foo ( "abcd" );
```

Then I expect `f.id` to contain the id of the `Foo` record which was loaded. However, its value is actually `0`. By running this code through a debugger, I've found that `Foo.load()` is called before the `public long id = 0` line is executed. So, although `load()` is called and it does set `id` and other fields to their correct values, those values are then overwritten by the `public long id = 0;` and other variable declarations..

I've never come across this issue before, usually the values set in a constructor overwrite the default values in the variable declaration. Is it because I'm calling load through `super` that the values are being overwritten? If so, is there a convenient fix for this?

Comment: The default value of `long` is `0L` and `String` is `null`. If you do a simple check to return an empty string instead of `null`, you can bypass this issue by removing the initial values.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel This class is just a snippet, I have over 10-12 fields total. I don't want to do `if` checks 10-12 times to avoid getting nullpointerexceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem with calling virtual methods in a constructor...

The order of execution is:

- BaseFoo variable initializers
- BaseFoo constructor body
- Foo variable initializers
- Foo constructor body

That behaviour is well documented in the [JLS, section 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

So *actually*, if you change these:

```
@Expose public long id = 0;
@Expose public long name =  "";
```

to

```
@Expose public long id;
@Expose public String name;
```

and then *conditionally* set `name` to "" if it's not already non-null by the time you get to the `Foo` constructor body, then I think you'll be okay.

However, I'd *strongly* advise you to approach this with a different design. Virtual method calls in constructors get really messy really quickly.

Comment: What if I renamed `BaseFoo(String key)` to `BaseFoo.load(String key)`, and from `Foo`'s constructor I did: `load( key )`, would that result in the values being set correctly?